# How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\alpha}}^*$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Let $p\in\mathbb{N}, p>2$ be a prime number and $\alpha\in\mathbb{N},\alpha\geqslant 2$.
> >     How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\alpha}}^*$ have?

What I know is that
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\alpha}}^*=\left\{x+p^{\alpha}\mathbb{Z}| x\in\left\{0,\ldots,p^{\alpha}-1\right\}: gcd(x,p^{\alpha})=1\right\}\\=\left\{x+p^{\alpha}\mathbb{Z}| x\in\left\{0,\ldots,p^{\alpha}-1\right\}: gcd(x,p)=1\right\}
$$

so the remaining question (which is probably a silly one, but I do not know) is for how many $x\in\left\{0,\ldots,p^{\alpha}-1\right\}$ it is $gcd(x,p)=1$.

How can I answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. See some easy concrete examples first (e.g. $p^\alpha=8$ or $9$ or $27$).

You will recognise that every $p$th number is a multiple of $p$, but no more. So, until $x=p^\alpha$ we have exactly $\displaystyle\frac{p^\alpha}p$ numbers $x$ that are divisible by $p$, and the rest will have $\gcd(x,p)=1$.

Comment: You mean $p^{\alpha}/p$ numbers x that are divisible by $p$, or?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).  It's defined as follows: $\varphi(n)$ is the number of $k$ in $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ such that $\gcd(k,n) = 1$, i.e. the number of elements relatively prime to $n$.  There are many helpful answers in [this post](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/629933/properties-of-the-euler-totient-function/636466) that address why $\varphi(p^n) = (p-1)(p^{n-1})$ for primes $p$.