# Show that $\phi(p^e)=p^e-p^{e-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, totient-function

In an exercise I was asked to show that if $R$ is a ring with relatively prime ideals $I_1,I_2$ then $R/I \cong R/I_1 \oplus R/I_2$ where $I=I_1 \cap I_2$ and $\oplus$ is the direct sum. A follow on exercise asks to show, using the above result, that $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m) \varphi(n)$ provided that gcd($m,n)=1$ and $\varphi$ is the Euler-Phi function. It then asks to show *also* that $\varphi(p^e)=p^e-p^{e-1}$ if $p$ is prime. How am I supposed to show that $\varphi(p^e)=p^e-p^{e-1}$ using the above result? Or is it unrelated?

Comment: I think it is unrelated, and a simple counting (perhaps with induction) gives the equality.

Comment: For a simple proof see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#2.29_.CF.86.28pk.29_.3D_pk_.E2.88.92_pk.E2.88.921_.3D_pk.E2.88.921.28p_.E2.88.92_1.29). Then we can write $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ and use that $\phi$ is multiplicative to compute $\phi(n)$.

Comment: There are several proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629933/properties-of-the-euler-totient-function/636466#636466).  As Dietrich says, knowing that $\phi$ is (number-theoretically) multiplicative means that its action on prime powers determines it completely.

Answer (score 1):

The supplementary question has nothing to do with the abstract Chinese remainder theorem. It doesn't require induction either.

$\varphi(p^{e})$ is the number of classes of integers which are units modulo $p^e$. Each such class of congruence has a unique representative in the form $\;a_0+a_1 p+\dots a_{e-1} p^{e-1},\quad 0\le a_0,a_0,\dots a_{e-1}\le p-1 $ (to see this, write any integer in base $p$).

Now any $n=a_0+a_1 p+\dots a_{e-1} p^{e-1}$ is a unit mod. $p^e$ if and only if $a_0\ne 0$, while the $a_i$s, for $i\ge 0$ can have any value. Thus the distinct representatives for units mod.  $p^e$  are
$$(p-1)p^{e-1}=p^e-p^{e-1}\quad\text{in number}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A number is relatively prime with $p^e$ if and only if it is not divisible by $p$.

There are $p^e$ numbers in total $\{1,2,3,..,p^e\}$. From those, exactly $p^{e-1}$ are divisible by $p$:
$$\{ 1\cdot p, 2 \cdot p, 3 \cdot p, 4 \cdot p ,..., p^{e-1} \cdot p \}$$

Therefore, there are $p^e-p^{e-1}$ numbers in the list not divisible by $p$.