# What is the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})^ \times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

What is the size of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})^ \times$ if p is a prime number?

At first, I thought that the size would be $p^n-1$, but now I think perhaps not because $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})$ might have more than one non-invertible element.

Comment: Count the numbers that are not relatively prime with $p^n$ like $p, 2p , 3p , ... p^2 , 2p^2 ... $

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629933/properties-of-the-euler-totient-function)

Comment: Could you explain why the number of $p, 2p, 3p, \cdots, p^2, 2p^2,\cdots, (p-1)p^{n-1}, p^n$ is $p^{n-1}$? I just compute it and get $(p-1)\times(n-1)+1$, I think maybe there is something wrong with me@DionelJaime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_product_formula) (since it can be [shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) that $|(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times|=\phi(n))$ that $$|(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times|=n\prod_{p|n}\bigg(1-\frac1p\bigg)$$Where $p$ are primes that divide $n$.

Note that for $n = p^k$, only $p$ is the prime that divides $n$. As such, $$|(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)^\times|=p^k\bigg(1-\frac1p\bigg)=p^k-p^{k-1}$$

Comment: I think if he knew this result he wouldn’t be having a problem with the question.

Comment: @DionelJaime, now they know the result.

Comment: @Downvoter Any feedback you'd like to share?

Answer (score 2):

The non-units is $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z\;$ are the congruence classes  of the integers which are divisible by $p$. Representatives of each of these classes are obtained as $\bigl\{kp\mid 0\le k \le p^{n-1}-1\bigr\}\;$ (or $1\le k\le p^{n-1}$), which are $p^{n-1}$.

Hence the number of units is $\;p^n-p^{n-1}=p^{n-1}(p-1)$.